# SQL server /.net String connection

Tags: json, .net, sql-server, ubuntu, connection

I'm on ubuntu system trying to connect to my local sql server from my (ASP).net application
i configured the string connection

`"ConnectionStrings": {     "DefaultConnection": "Server=localhost\\mssqllocaldb;Database=temaintdb;User Id=sa;     Password=******;"      },`

also i enabled the TCP/Ip ,and allowed the port 1433, and tried a remote access to my db and it's worked
but when i'm trying to update my database from my .net i'm facing this error :
[dotnet ef database update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Axz8.png)

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.
The server was not found or was not accessible.
Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
(provider: TCP Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught).
```

i already checked :
-string connection
-sql server remote access
-Firewall or network configuration
-Enabled TCP/IP protocole

```
chabba@chabba:~$ systemctl status mssql-server
```

```
   ● mssql-server.service - Microsoft SQL Server Database Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mssql-server.service; enabled; vendor >
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2023-05-23 12:48:52 +01; 4min 16s ago
       Docs: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux
    Main PID: 1158 (sqlservr)
      Tasks: 170
     Memory: 1.9G
     CGroup: /system.slice/mssql-server.service
             ├─1158 /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr
             └─1646 /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr
    chabba@chabba:~$ sudo ufw status
    [sudo] password for chabba: 
    Status: active
```

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
1433                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
1433 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             

1433                       ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                  
1433 (v6)                  ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6) `
```

Answer (score 0):

yeah, that was one of the solution i found in internet, ik it sounds stupid cause i have no instance set in my server but i wanted to check it
the acctual string i'm using is   "ConnectionStrings": {
"DefaultConnection": "Server=localhost;Database=temaintdb;User Id=sa;Password=*********;"
},
and the probleme is that in my project i've multiple appsettings, and i forgot to change the string connection in all of them.
thank you for answering me

Comment: This is more of a comment than an Answer. I am aware that you do not have enough reputation to comment, but you can suggest an edit to the question if applicable, and upvote it in addition to marking it as Accepted, as an additional form of feedback.